# C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lblosc -lkea -lsz ERROR: compilation failed for package 'sf' in R

Tags: r-sf, r-package

I'm updating sf version from 1.0-9 to 1.0-10 by using `install.packages("sf")` in Rstudio, but an error occured as follows:

```
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lblosc
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkea
C:\rtools42\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lsz
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'sf'
```

Maybe someone can give me some advice? Thanks a lot.

I have just updated my R version from 4.2.0 to 4.2.2 using `library(installr);updateR()`. Then I opened my Rstudio and updated all R packages, but I failed to update **sf** package.I hope someone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi! You may want to check the following page: https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/2118

Comment: Apparently, you just need to install the latest Rtools!